# Change string index to datetime using chained function

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import io

data = """value          
"2015-09-25 00:46"    71.925000
"2015-09-25 00:47"    71.625000
"2015-09-25 00:48"    71.333333
"2015-09-25 00:49"    64.571429
"2015-09-25 00:50"    72.285714"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I can change the dataFrame index to datetime as follows:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I would like to change the index to datetime as part of my `tweak_frame` function using a chaining approach:

```
def tweak_frame(_df):
  return df.assign(new_col=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out after posting.  I used `set_index`

```
def tweak_frame(_df):
  return (df.assign(new_col=1)
  .set_index(pd.to_datetime(_df.index)))

tweak_frame(df).index
```

Returns:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-25 00:46:00', '2015-09-25 00:47:00',
               '2015-09-25 00:48:00', '2015-09-25 00:49:00',
               '2015-09-25 00:50:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```